# A good approach to write a cms application/software

Tags: architecture

I want to know some tips of good approach to write a cms application/software. Its not related to coding etc but please give tips for seo, designing architect, what could be the database model etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too big a question to be answered usefully here. My suggestion would be to study an existing open-source CMS implementation, for example [this](http://dev.cmsmadesimple.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I have lot of CMS project like DNN, Jm, Joomla etc. but I want to know the exact scenario. These all have a different architectre and approaches

Comment: @Gaurav, I don't really understand how we can tell you a "scenario". Architecture comes from requirements, and we can't invent those for you. A database model would come from the use cases we need to support.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your support. Actually the CMS should be customizable at user end, means every user can add/remove functionality as per his/her need. These are primary requirements

Comment: Adding functionality would usually be a programming task, no? Any serious functionality implies logic, and persistence and querying and reporting. Most attempts to make these truly end-user extensible end up with some kind of mini programming language. This requirement is very hard to implement well. Even to write a pluggable system, extensible by programming is demanding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I found the solution myself. Its my fault I recognized the task wrongly actually its called a Database Driven Web sites/applications. Its also a CMS in other words.
Now, I have to prepare Architecture for the same. I really appreciate your efforts.